# Getting Wrong output in scope of variables in java

Tags: java

I'm getting wrong output for this. I'm getting 0 as output for every case. I know it's because of wrong use of scope of variables. limitation elements should be declared private only.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Difference {
private int[] elements;
public int maximumDifference;
// Add your code here
Difference(int elements[])
{
this.elements = elements;
}

int computeDifference()
{

int maximumDifference=0;
int l=elements.length;
for(int i=0; i<l; i++) 
{
for(int j=i+1; j<l; j++)  
{  
if (Math.abs(elements[i]-elements[j]) > maximumDifference){
maximumDifference = (Math.abs(elements[i]-elements[j]));
}
}
}
return maximumDifference;
}
} 

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
int[] a = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
a[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
sc.close();

Difference difference = new Difference(a);

difference.computeDifference();

System.out.print(difference.maximumDifference);
}
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code. It's impossible to read like this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Just one problem, you're missing the question. "Getting wrong output" + dumping your non-indented code here is not even close to being a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

Please next time indent your code.

You just need to remove the type `int` to `maximumDifference` in `computeDifference()`, because in the method you are overriding the class field you declared before, which remains equal to 0 when you call the method.

Another solution would be just to `System.out.print(difference.computeDifference());` in your main, since `computeDifference()` returns the variable in its scope, that has the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one change. Assign result of `difference.computeDifference()` method call to variable `difference.maximumDifference` :

```
difference.maximumDifference= difference.computeDifference();

        System.out.print(difference.maximumDifference);
```